# Checking coordinates within range in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
randomNumber = random.randint(1,625)
randomNumber2 = random.randint(1,420)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,(randomNumber,randomNumber2,50,50),5)
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
   y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

I am wondering how it is possible to check that the mouse, when clicked, has clicked on the square that has been drawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
randomNumber = random.randint(1,625)
randomNumber2 = random.randint(1,420)
my_rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,(randomNumber,randomNumber2,50,50),5)

if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
   x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

   is_inside = my_rect.collidepoint(x, y) 

   if is_inside:
       #DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO
```

**Try this.**